# Ajax request works on Linux but not on my windows localhost

Tags: php, ajax, linux, windows

I'm unable to figure this out for quite some time now. The ajax request works perfectly on a linux machine set up remotely but renders a 403 error when I try the same request on a windows machine.

**Linux machine request log**

[image: This is the request log for Linux environment]

**Windows local machine request log**

[image: This is the request log for Windows environemnt]

Thanks in advance

Comment: @JonasLochmann In Linux i get a JSON response as expected but i get a 403 Forbidden page in windows. The backend is entirely PHP.

Comment: the application can enter in the directory ajax? this directory has the correct permissions?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with .htaccess. Apparently, the same .htaccess file behaves differently on Linux and Windows environment. I could resolve the issue by completely removing the .htaccess file in Windows(local environment). Though, I know this is not the most ideal of the solutions, it works.
Thank you @Sfili_81. Your comment on folder permissions prompted me to think in this direction.